# Dealing with "non-numerical characters" when expecting an integer input

Tags: c, char, integer, scanf

I need a help with the following function, it's expecting an integer input; and when I insert something like "F" (non-numerical characters ), the program gets stuck, it doesn't show any output or let me insert more inputs.
how can this be fixed?

```
int input_legality(int game_board[FIELD_ROWS][FIELD_COLS])
{
    int input=0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(scanf("%d", &input)==1)
        {
            if(input==DOWN || input==LEFT || input==RIGHT || input==UP)
            {
                return input;
            }
            else
                if(input==EXIT)
                {
                    printf("\n program exited by user \n");
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                    if(input==PRINT)
                    {
                        printField(game_board);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"your step is undefined, please try another one\n");
                        continue;
                    }
        }
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/
You should handle error situation (your "if(scanf("%d", &input)==1)" does not have "else").

Comment: I've already tried this, it doesn't work, gives exactly the same result. (I tried else continue;)

Comment: What do you mean "exactly the same"? If you put, say, break there, it can't be the same.

Comment: Please format your code and provide a minimal example (main function, expected input, expected output). Currently your indents do not match the braces, so I think your braces might be wrong.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497111/reading-character-with-scanf?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that "F" is left in stdin if scanf() does not read an integer.
One answer would be to scan a string if an integer is not detected...

Try to add something like

```
char bla[256];
scanf("%s",bla);
```

At the end of the while loop (or in case scanf("%d) failed)

Here is a basic "main" code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DOWN 0
#define UP 1
#define LEFT 2
#define RIGHT 3

#define EXIT 4
#define PRINT 5
int input_legality()
{
    int input=0;
    while(1)
    {
        if(scanf("%d", &input)==1)
        {


            if(input==DOWN || input==LEFT || input==RIGHT || input==UP)
            {
                return input;
            }

            else{
                if(input==EXIT)
                {
                    printf("\n program exited by user \n");
                    return 1;
                }
                else{
                    if(input==PRINT)
                    {
                        printf("ble %d \n",input);
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fprintf(stderr,"your step is undefined, please try another one\n");
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //while(getchar() != EOF); 

        //fflush(stdin);
        char bla[256];
        scanf("%s", bla);

    }  
    return 0;
}

int main ( int argc , char * argv [] )
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<42;i++){
        input_legality();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This scanf is the easy way : some other may be better.
Using switch-case may clarify the code.
Bye,

Francis

Comment: Wow Francis , that works perfectly for me, brilliant! I added this:   char bla[256];
scanf("%s", bla);

Answer (score 0):

Always, always, *always* get (interactive) input a line at a time. That's how the user conceives it, so the program logic should be similar.

The POSIX `getline` function is very useful. Alternatively, you can use `fgets` and deal with overlong lines yourself (perhaps implementing `getline`, since it is pretty easy).

Once you've fetched a line of input, parse it (being sure to error on trailing garbage) using any method: `sscanf`, `strtok_r`, `strtou?ll?`, ...