# Taking input from user using do while loop in c

Tags: c, algorithm

I am creating a program for generating next prime number, for which I need to take user input.I am using do-while loop but it doesn't stop to take input for second time. Please guide me where I am doing wrong. Thanks!
This is my code snippet

```
int 
main()
{ 
int val=1;
char input;
do
{
    val=nextprime(val);
    printf("\n%d\t",val);

    printf("Next Prime number? Y or N ");
    scanf("%c",&input);
 } 
while(input != 'N' && input != 'n');
return 0;
```

}

output I am getting is :

```
2   Next Prime number? Y or N y

3   Next Prime number? Y or N 
5   Next Prime number? Y or N y

7   Next Prime number? Y or N 
11  Next Prime number? Y or N y

13  Next Prime number? Y or N 
17  Next Prime number? Y or N y

19  Next Prime number? Y or N 
23  Next Prime number? Y or N y

29  Next Prime number? Y or N 
31  Next Prime number? Y or N n
```

Comment: Try `" %c"` for your format string. See the second answer to [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744776/simple-c-scanf-does-not-work). There are a ton of duplicates on this; that was the first one I ran across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer here: [Reading a single character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419954/reading-a-single-character-in-c)

When you press 'Y' you press enter, which stand in the input buffer, and is read on the next iteration of your loop.

You need to use:

```
scanf(" %c",&input);
```

With leading space to ignore last caracters in the input buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The stdin will contain `y\n` (y followed by a carriage return). Since your code treats any character other than `N` or `n` as yes, it calculates 2 new primes if you enter y followed by a carriage return.

To skip whitespace when reading a single char, put a space before the scan code:

```
scanf(" %c",&input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a space before `%c` in the `scanf` will solve the issue.

This is done because `scanf` does not consume the `\n` character after you enter the first character and leaves it in the `stdin`.As the Enter key(`\n`) is also a character,it gets consumed by the next `scanf` call and thus,your loop gets executed once again.The space before the `%c` will discard all blanks like spaces.

An alternative way to overcome this would be to add `getchar();` after the `scanf` to eat up the `\n` but I prefer the first one.

Comment: I also prefer the first one, because it has more consistent behaviour if the user enters multiple characters at once.