# Why is adding a leading space in a scanf format string recommended?

Tags: c, string, controls, scanf

I am currently reading this book "C11 Programming for beginners" and in the scanf() chapter it says:

"Always add a leading space before the first control string character to ensure accurate character input." As in:

```
scanf(" %s", whatever);
```

The control string `" %s"`, has a space before it.
I know it sounds pretty self-explanatory, but I don't really get what could go wrong, and how this space ensures accurate character input.

Comment: That better come with a big caveat  Single char `%c` fetching is likely the dominant reasoning behind that sledge-hammer statement, and failure to provide the specifics like that make me question the voodoo teaching ideology of that text. "Always do <blah>" without some sort of explanation *why* you should follow that mantra, and how things can go wrong if you *don't*, are often more confusing than helpful (case in point, your posting this question...). Anyway, you may find [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419954/reading-a-single-character-in-c/14419972#14419972) helpful.

Comment: Is that book really called *C11 Programming for beginners*? Wasn't `scanf` superseded by `scanf_s` in C11?

Comment: @AndersMarziTornblad: No.  `scanf_s()` is an optional function defined in [Annex K §3.5.3.4 The `scanf_s` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.3.5.3.4).  Microsoft would rather you used their version of [`scanf_s()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-170)  but few other compilers/libraries have implemented it.  The signatures of these functions agree, something which is not guaranteed with the `_s` (safer) functions.

Comment: `"%s"` means: ignore optional leading whitespace and read a whitespace delimited string... `" %s"` means ignore optional whitespace and then ignore optional leading whitespace and read a whitespace delimited string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@WhozCraig well stated shortcomings to this advice.  Its comes without rational nor detail.  Further it does not apply to `"%s"` as `"%s"` consumes leading white-space with or without a leading space.

A leading white-space, be it `' '`, `'\t'`, `'\n'`, etc. all do the same thing: direct `scanf()` to consume and not store optional leading white-space `char`.  This is useful as typical usage of previous `scanf()` does not consume the user's `'\n'` from the <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
scanf("%d", &some_int);
scanf("%c", &some_char);  // some_char is bound to get the value '\n'
```

All `scanf()` input specifiers ignore leading spaces, except 3: `"%c"`, `"%n"`, `"%[]"`.

Simple directives *do* benefit with the leading space as in the following.  Previous left-over white-space is consumed before `'$'`.

```
int Money;
scanf(" $%d", &Money);
```

Often, though not always, a leading space before `"%c"` is beneficial as when reading a single `char` of user input.

```
char ch;
scanf(" %c", &ch);
```

What is most wrong with the advice is that 1) when using `"%s"`, supplying a width parameter is essential to robust code and 2) the return value should be checked.

```
char buf[30];
int cnt = scanf("%29s", buf);
if (cnt != 1) Handle_NoInput_or_EOF_IOError();
```

Note that all the conversion specifiers except `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n` skip *leading* white space automatically, so the advice is not really relevant with `%s`, or `%d` or `%lf`, etc.

Lastly, I recommend using `fgets()` rather than `scanf()` whenever one can — which is usually the case.

Comment: Thank you chux :) As far as I understood, when using scanf() with "%c", "%n", or "%[]", scanf will store a leading space in a char. How does it store in the same char if a char can hold a single character only?

Comment: @Stanley `scanf(" %c", &ch);` will consume and discard optional leading white-space.  Then will store a non-white-space `char` in `ch`.  `scanf("%c", &ch);` will store the first `char` that comes along into `ch`.     `"%n"`, or `"%[]"` work quite differently.

Comment: Really nice answer, appreciate your effort to this site!

Answer (score 2):

*"Always add a leading space before the first control string character to ensure accurate character input."*

This is to consume any trailing white space characters or leading white space characters in the `stdin` that might have been left by previous user input (like the `carriage return`), before the `scanf` reads the user input.  Of course, all the conversions except `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n` do this automatically, so the advice is not really relevant with `%s`.