# The scanf and gets work differently about put '\0' in an array?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, gets

I am getting and displaying names, and stop the program when I type enter key. At the below code I get the correctly result (I know "gets" is deprecated):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char name[50];

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%s", name);

        if(name[0]=='\0')
            break;
        else
            printf("Name entered: %s\n", name);
    }
}
```

But when I try to use scanf:

```
printf("Nome: ");
scanf("%s", nome);
```

The condition `name[0]=='\0'` never is true this time. Why? The `'\0'` works differently in these functions?

Comment: Because `Enter Key` is `\n`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26391465/why-is-adding-a-leading-space-in-a-scanf-format-string-recommended check this out to understand @Shank comment

Comment: Thank you, Olivier.

Comment: Um... So, what is the difference between the vesions? I don't see any, besides some strange `nome` instead of `name` in the second one. And why are you mentioning `gets` when there's no `gets` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Sorry AnT,  "nome" means "name". And `scanf("%s", name);` actually is `gets(name);`.

Answer (score 1):

If `scanf` cannot assign a value to a variable (because the input stream has a whitespace, terminating the 'string'), it doesn't clear it out; the reason is partly that not all variables have an obvious 'clear' state.

So after your scanf, the `nome` still contains whatever it contained before. You need to check if scanf was able to assign a variable instead, by testing its return value:
`if (scanf(...) == 1)` - which means 'did scanf successfully assign one variable?'

Comment: If I put some names I can display this name, it means that scanf worked. But when I type enter (no characters) then the program doesn't end. So I guess the '\0' is not in the array "name". Is that?

Comment: Yes, the '\n' tells scanf to _stop reading_, and it doesn't copy it in the name, it _stops_.

Comment: Sorry guys, "nome" means "name". In the first code `scanf("%s", name);` actually is `gets(name);`.

Answer (score -1):

Using "scanf" the variable doesn't become a string but with "gets" the variable (name) becomes string because "gets" automatically puts '\0' in it?