# scan arbitrary number of chars in c

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I want to read an unknown number of characters, which are not greater than 10.

```
char word[10];
for( i=0;i<10;i++){
    if( !scanf("%c",&word[i])){ //terminate with 0
        getchar();
        break;
    }   
}
```

The problem is that  number is also an character, so the if statement won't be executed. Is there any other solution to terminate the input of characters for example with 0.

Comment: hint: `scanf()` does not return the scanned entry, it returns the number of items scanned and matched scussfully.

Comment: So if I type in 0, then nothing is scanned?

Comment: Why not? but it does not return a 0, in case the scanning is successful.

Comment: So in that case I have to write: scanf(..)==0.

Comment: I suggest to use getchar() for reading single chars. This post is related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419954/reading-a-single-character-in-c

Comment: "*The problem is that number is also an character, so the if statement won't be executed.*" - Could you elaborate that? The `if` statement will *always* get executed. Not clear what you mean with "number is also an character" as well. Please add more details, actual input and output and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest:

```
char word[10];

if( scanf("%9s",word) != 1 )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "scanf for (max 9 char word) failed\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}
```

using `%9s` because the `%s` input format conversion specifier always appends a NUL byte to the input.

If the input is less than 9 characters, that is properly handled.

If the input is greater than 9 characters, the `9` modifier will stop the input, so the input buffer is not overflowed.  Such an overflow would result in undefined behavior.

Comment: So in order to input 10 characters, I have to change  %9 to %10 and char word[11], so that in position word[10] is the NUL byte?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `do..while` loop. Something like (pseudo-code)

```
int keep_looping = 1;
int counter = 0;
do {
    ret = scanf(" %c",&word[counter]);
    if (!ret) continue;  //can use more cleanup and error check
    if (word[counter] == '0') keep_looping =0;
    counter++;
    }
while (keep_looping && counter < 10)
```

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio maybe I don;t, care to enlight?

Comment: Not possible. I'm drawing blanks, too. ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Why does the while loop terminate if keep_looping is 0?

Comment: because the controlling expression has to evaluate to a TRUE value (1) to continue looping.

Comment: @Boris If A subcondition of `&&` evaluates to `0`, the main condition is not `true` and thus the loop doesn't iterate anymore.

Comment: But the value of 1 outside the loop will be substituted with 0?

Comment: Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the character that you just read (at word[i])  and if not valid (e.g not alpabetical) than break.