# C/C++ Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'gradeLetter' was corrupted. Visual Studio 2019. How to solve this problem?

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

//Counting GPA
int main()
{
    float finalGrade, totalQualityPoints = 0, totalHours = 0;
    int hours, qualityPoints, subjectsCount, points = 0;
    char gradeLetter;

    printf("How many subjects do you have? ");
    scanf("%d", &subjectsCount);

    for (int i = 1; i <= subjectsCount; i++) {

        printf("\nEnter the number of hours for your %d subject: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &hours);
        printf("Enter the grade letter for your %d subject: ", i);
        scanf("%s", &gradeLetter);
        printf("\n");
        
        if (gradeLetter == 'A' || gradeLetter == 'a') {
            points = 4;
        } else if (gradeLetter == 'B' || gradeLetter == 'b') {
            points = 3;
        } else if (gradeLetter == 'C' || gradeLetter == 'c') {
            points = 2;
        } else if (gradeLetter == 'D' || gradeLetter == 'd') {
            points = 1;
        } else if (gradeLetter == 'F' || gradeLetter == 'f') {
            points = 0;
        }
        
        //At each iteration, this variable adds up the previous value for each subject
        qualityPoints = hours * points;
        totalHours += hours;
        totalQualityPoints += qualityPoints;

    }

    printf("\nTotal hours: %.2f Total QP: %.2f ",totalHours, totalQualityPoints);

    finalGrade = totalQualityPoints / totalHours;
    printf("\nYour GPA is: %.2f ", finalGrade);
}
```

> Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'gradeLetter' was corrupted. Visual Studio 2019. How to solve this problem?

> The output to the screen is carried out, the program actually reads and outputs gpa. But at the end the compiler outputs a warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding:

```
scanf("%s", &gradeLetter);
```

1. is expecting to read a single character, not a string
2. needs to consume/discard any left over '\n' left in `stdin`

Suggest:

```
scanf(" %c", &gradeLetter);
```

Notice the use of the `%c` input format conversion specifier

Notice the space before the conversion specifier to consume any leading 'white space' like the left over '\n' in `stdin`

regarding the group of statements similar to:

```
if (gradeLetter == 'A' || gradeLetter == 'a') {
```

Suggest replacing that whole group with the single statement:

```
#include <ctype.h>
....
points = 5 - (tolower( gradeLetter ) - 'a' );
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line `scanf("%s", &gradeLetter);` you are trying to read a character *string* (i.e. a `nul`-terminated *array* of `char` elements) into a *single* character. For the latter (as in your case), you need the `%c` format:

```c
scanf("%c", &gradeLetter);
```

The code, as you have it, will potentially be writing to memory beyond the actual `gradeLetter` variable (which will be allocated on the stack) and, thus, you will likely be corrupting the stack.

Note: Using the `%c` format specifier will also likely cause issues with a 'leftover' newline ("enter") character in the input buffer. This issue is addressed here: [Reading a single character in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14419954/10871073).

Comment: Got it! Thanks dude!

Comment: this 'correction' will read the left over '\n' from the prior call to `scanf("%d", &hours);` because the `%c` input format conversion specifier does NOT consume/discard leading 'white space'

Comment: @user3629249 Did I say otherwise? The issue is fully addressed in the topic I linked.

Comment: It is considered 'off topic' to 'only' link to another page.  The answer should include the relevant text from the linked page AND the proposed code in the answer is NOT correct.